# tmux maximize/minimize pane bug -- "Session not found: tmp"

Tags: tmux

**description of what's happening:**

- when minimizing a maximized pane, this message appears at bottom of terminal window: `"Session not found: tmp"`
- pane appears to return to same place as initial/previous session
- but the new tmp window (that was opened when the pane was first maximized) fails to close and appears in the list of windows (in the status bar at the bottom of tmux)

my hunch is `kill-window -t tmp` (in the below .tmux.conf code) is where things break. since executing a command in the tmp window appears to rename the window, `kill-window -t tmp` won't work.

so my question is: **how could i alter .tmux.conf to prevent this from happening?**

**steps to recreate bug:**

(note: you would need to have modified .tmux.conf for these commands to work)

- start tmux and create session w/ at least two panes
- maximize one pane using `[prefix] + [up]`
- execute a shell command in maximized pane (*)
- minimize pane using `[prefix] + [down]`

(*) if pane is maximized and minimized w/out executing a command in the shell this problem does not appear to occur. i.e. if you're editing a file in a pane, then maximize that pane, and only edit/save the file (w/out exiting and then executing another command), then minimize -- the bug doesn't occur.

**30s youtube clip showing what happens:** http://youtu.be/WMdOeJdOYuU

**code that might be causing the error (from ~/.tmux.conf):**

`unbind Up
bind Up new-window -d -n tmp \; swap-pane -s tmp.0 \; select-window -t tmp
unbind Down
bind Down last-window \; swap-pane -s tmp.0 \; kill-window -t tmp`

**[edit: HERE IS THE SOLUTION]**

thanks to a helpful #tmux irc'er (who has this link and whom i will happily give credit) this question is solved. i don't yet have enough cred to answer this question so i'm posting the solution here.

the solution is to add `set-window-option -g allow-rename off` to ~/.tmux.conf

this works b/c `tmp` doesn't get renamed so `kill-window -t tmp` can properly execute.

(*thx for the help and feel free to answer this so i can give you credit!*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `allow-rename` set to off, at least for that one window:

```
set-window-option -g allow-rename off
```

Comment: perhaps this will also be helpful to others who followed  code examples in the pragmatic tmux book. thx again!